# Pass object property to service from component, or not to?

Tags: angular

I'm fairly new to Observables, Promises, Angular 2 and trying to understand architecture and best practices.

I have an app component that looks like this:

```
export class AppComponent {

  items: Item[] = // some Items in here
  totalSalesLastThirtyDays: number = 0

  constructor (private itemTransactionsService: ItemTransactionsService) {}

  ngOnInit() { 
    this.itemTransactionsService.getLastThirtyDays(this.items)
  }
}
```

I have a service that looks like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class ItemTransactionsService {

  constructor (private http: Http) {}

  getLastThirtyDays(items: Item[]) {
    /// How do I know when all the observables have completed
    /// and I can compute the totalSalesLastThirtyDays?
    /// Where would I set totalSalesLastThirtyDays property of AppComponent?
    for (let item of items) {
        this.getItemTransactions(item).subscribe(result => {
                        // console.dir("result = " + result);
                        item.soldInLast15Days = result[0]
                        item.soldInLast30Days = result[1]                      
                      },
                      error =>  {})
    }
  }



  getItemTransactions(item: Item): Observable<any> {
    // Work work work
    return this.http.post(this.url, body, options)
                    .map(this.extractData)
                    .catch(this.handleError);
  }
}
```

Ultimately, when all the getItemTransactions have been invoked and returned on each item, I want to compute the totalSalesLastThirtyDays, where totalSalesLastThirtyDays is a property on my AppComponent.

What would be the "Angular 2" architectural way of getting this done?

Do I pass the totalSalesLastThirtyDays by reference to the service?
Do I use an observable on getLastThirtyDays to pass back a computed totalSalesLastThirtyDays to be set in the AppComponent?
How do I know that all the API calls in the for-loop have completed and I can compute the totalSalesLastThirtyDays?

I'm not sure what would be a good title for this question - so please suggest if you can think of one.

Answer (score 1):

I would use RXjs zip operator here.

**Service**

```js
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class ItemTransactionsService {

  constructor (private http: Http) {}

  getLastThirtyDays(items: Item[]) {
    return Observable.zip(
      ...items.map(item => {
        return this.getItemTransactions(item);
      })
   ).map((data: Array<any>) => {
     // You get array of responses here
     // Do your calculations and return it
     return data;
   });
 }

 getItemTransactions(item: Item): Observable<any> {
   // Work work work
   return this.http.post(this.url, body, options)
                .map(this.extractData)
                .catch(this.handleError);
 }
}
```

**Component**

```js
export class AppComponent {

  items: Item[] = // some Items in here
  totalSalesLastThirtyDays: number = 0

  constructor (private itemTransactionsService: ItemTransactionsService) {}

  ngOnInit() { 
    this.itemTransactionsService.getLastThirtyDays(this.items)
      .subscribe(totalSales => {
        this.totalSalesLastThirtyDays = totalSales;
      })
  }
}
```